# How should I divide my Clojure system into mutable / immutable parts?

Tags: clojure

Which of the following makes sense when dividing up my Clojure application into immutable parts?

- Separate into different name-spaces the mutable/immutable parts
- Add prefixes to defns which have side effects
- Use the Clojure "doc" to explain this
- Mix and match as you wish

I need to know this as I have a Clojure application which talks to databases, application servers and a stateful web framework, so I want my application to be as easy to maintain / read as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some techniques that have worked for me:

- Divide your namespaces and files by module/purpose rather than anything else. This makes more logical sense and helps you keep your design and dependencies clean.
- Use "!" to indicate functions that have side effects, e.g. "swap!". Usually you should avoid side effects as much as possible, so it's a bit of a design smell if you see this happening too often
- Try to avoid *any* mutable state in your library / utility functions. Not only does this usually give you a better API design, it's also much easier to test....
- Keep application-specific mutable state to a small number of top-level defines. It's possible for example to use just a single top-level ref to an immutable map to store all your mutable data
- It's helpful to document with examples that you can cut and paste into the REPL so that you can test things quickly or customise to a more complex use case. Again this is much easier if everything is pure.

Comment: I should note that this is basically the exact same advice I'd give in any language...

Answer (score 2):

Here is what my approach would be:

1. Don't divide the namespaces according to mutability/immutability unless you are writing a collections library or something similar. Use namespaces to indicate the logical partitions of your code, like `ui`, `core`, `util` etc.
2. By default keep all functions pure and hence do not use any prefix by default. State should be generally stored in `ref`s and `atom`s defined as `def`s. Use names that indicate the satefullness, like `userNameStore`.
3. Document everything, all functions and vars. Or at least the public ones.
4. Mix and match but do not do so on an ad-hoc basis. Clearly structure your code so that the mutable state is limited and is well focussed.